# POVray mode minor change sought

Tags: major-mode

[POVray](https://www.povray.org) is a scripting language used to define 3-dimensional graphics.

[POVray mode for emacs](https://github.com/melmothx/pov-mode) provides text coloring, automatic indenting, etc. when developing a script on emacs.

For the most part, this works very well despite the fact that the last change to the mode was 5 years ago. POVray itself doesn't change very much either. But it does change. Specifically, a new keyword elseif has been added, and I would like this mode to incorporate this change.

I looked at the above linked GitHub page, and could not find a place to comment, or even a way to message the author. So maybe I am asking my question in the wrong place, and I just need a clue about GitHub.

I looked at the pov-mode.el file, to see if I could do this myself. My idea was to add in an #elseif directive, possibly within a parenthesized or clause, everywhere I saw the #else directive. But I am not familiar with Lisp and I am not sure whether the desired consequences would result. I would probably also have to search through instances of the #if directive as well.

Advice on how to either contact the author (melmothx on GitHub) or learn more about Lisp would be welcome.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Go to the GitHub site, click on "Issues" and create a new one describing your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You should file an “issue” on GitHub. Technically this is more of a feature request than a bug report, but GitHub lumps all such things together.

You could also just try adding the “elseif” to the regex in the `pov-all-keyword-matcher` variable at https://github.com/melmothx/pov-mode/blob/master/pov-mode.el#L916. This seems to be what it uses to find keywords.

Comment: OK thanks for your help. I posted a new issue there as you suggested.

Comment: You’re welcome.